# Should I pick AWS Region based on where I am or where my customers are?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm based in the UK, so I have created my EC2 instances in Euro West (Ireland). I have one instance for data processing (not directly accessible to customers), and one Elastic Beanstalk instance that customers access.

But the majority of my customers are actually in US (50%),versus Europe (35%), Rest of the World (15%) so I'm wondering if I should have created the Elastic Beanstalk instance area, but also I need to transfer data between two instances can that be done in if in different areas, can a VPC be shared between areas ?

Im unclear on what factors to consider for choosing the availablity area

Comment: Assuming you are running a web service, I recommend you look into some service ([new relic](http://newrelic.com/real-user-monitoring) & [pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com/rum/)  come to mind) that will show you browser load times by region.

Comment: @jsermig so are you inferring it should be based on customer location ?

Comment: Well, what we did is set a max for average loading time. If customers in a particular region went above this limit, then we started to look into things we could improve. The reason I recommend using such tools is because we saw a few surprises and some things we assumed would be problem weren't problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it would make sense to place your servers closer to your customers when possible, but with that in mind, if your talking about a web application, you can push the caching closer to your customers using AWS Cloudfront which will geographically distribute your static resources (images, css files, js files etc) to dozens of edge locations around the world and improve response times with very little effort.

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/details/

Comment: Brennan okay, as my customers are split within EBS can I load balance over two regions (i.e US West, Europe West) or only within region?

Comment: In AWS terminology, **EBS** stands for _Elastic Block Store_, which is permanent storage for EC2 instances. _Elastic Beanstalk_ is an entirely different AWS all-together. But to answer your question (assuming you meant Elastic Beanstalk, of course), you can set up Route 53 to serve traffic to one region or another based on network latency from the customer.

Comment: @Ryan Parman, yes I meant EB okay so I can't split EB over regions, but I could two separate EB configurations in different regions and have Route53 deciding which one to send customer requests to.